# Xero developer account does not show organisation

Tags: xero-api

I am having problems to create an app and link to my organisation. I have been following the instructions on the documentation but for some unknown reason the organisation is lot listed.

Please refer to image attached for a better explanation.

I look forward to hear from you.

Kind regards

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same login for both your Xero Developer account and Xero main account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Xero Developer FAQ you might have the wrong permissions

> Why is my organisation missing from the drop down when authorising an
>   app?

If your organisation isn't showing in the organisation dropdown, this means either that you don't have Standard or Adviser level permissions in that organisation, or you already connected that particular app to the organisation.

https://developer.xero.com/faq/permissions/org-missing